# Error: Access to fetch from origin 'null'

Tags: javascript, html

Al realizar una clase para obtener los productos, me marca el error de:

> producto-detalles.html:1 Access to fetch at 'file:///C:/Users/emman/Desktop/jsondev-roloj-master/lista_productos.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.<

El código es el siguiente, el error no se donde está:

```
class Productos {
  async getProductos() {
    try {
            const result = await fetch('lista_productos.json')
            const data = await result.json()
            const productos = data.items
            return productos
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Si tu json es local, puedes intentar con 
`import someName from "./some/path/to/your/file.json";`

Comment: No puedes realizar llamadas AJAX si no usas el protocolo HTTP